# Return the count how many digits are 7 in the given number n

Tags: java

I'm writing a method for my CS151 class called countSevens(n). It Returns count how many digits are 7 in the given number n. This is what I have so far but I'm doing something wrong that I can't figure out.

```
public int countSevens(int n){
    int count = 0;
    String strI = Integer.toString(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < strI.length(); i++){
        if(strI.substring(i).equals("7")){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `substring` and find out what `strI.substring(i)` would return.

Comment: The one-arg `strI.substring` gives you the substring from that index until the end of the string. It’s too much for your need. Try `charAt`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with java streams

```
   public int countSevens(int n) {
        return (int) String.valueOf(n).chars().filter(ch -> ch == '7').count();
    }
```

- (int) - cast to an int type, in this particular case it safe to cast long to int, because we can't get a conversation error. In other cases it's better to use Math.toIntExact(long)
- String.valueOf(n) - convert to string
- chars() - return stream of chars
- filter(ch -> ch == '7') - filter all chars that equals to 7
- count() - returns the count of elements in this stream

Comment: a cast to `int` is enough, you will never get a `long` amount of 7s. That number would be way to large

Answer (score 1):

```
strI.substring(i)
```

Will return the part of string from i-character to the end.

Use `strI.charAt(i)` instead

Comment: I tried that and still could not get it to work, but thank you for clarifying substring that makes sense

Comment: I presume it doesn't work because you still use `equals`? `charAt` method return char and to compare chars you need to use `== '7'`

Comment: Oh yes i was using equals and i also tried to put just 7 or "7" but thats an int or string, i assume it would work now with '7', thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of `String.substring(int)`:

> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

So this will only count the last instance of a 7 in your number, and only if it's the last digit in the number.

Instead, try this:

```
if(strI.substring(i, i+1).equals("7"))
```

Or, since you're dealing with ints, you can avoid using strings altogether.  `n % 10` will get you the last digit, and `n /= 10` will bump the entire number right by one digit.  That should be enough to get you started on doing this without Strings.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I will also try to do it without strings :)

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of 7s in an integer:

```
int counter = 0;
int number = 237123;
String str_number = String.valueOf(number);
for(char c : str_number.toCharArray()){
    if(c == '7'){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple arithmetics:

```
public static int countSevens(int i) {
    int count = 0;
    for (i = i < 0 ? -i : i; i != 0; count += i % 10 == 7 ? 1 : 0, i /= 10);
    return count;
}
```

But who can read this? Not many, so here is a cleaner solution, applying the same logic:

```
public static int countSevens(int i) {
    int count = 0;

    // ignore negative numbers
    i = Math.abs(i);

    while(i != 0) {
        // if last digit is a 7
        if(i % 10 == 7) {
            // then increase the counter
            count++;
        }

        // remove the last digit
        i /= 10;

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @RobOhRob gotta have some fun sometimes ;)